# Translate SQL's first_value and partition by into SAS

Tags: oracle, sas, partitioning, proc-sql

I have this code in SQL

```
SELECT acc_id,
   time,
   approved_amount,
   balance,
   coalesce(approved_amount,
            first_value(balance) OVER (PARTITION BY acc_id
                                       ORDER BY time)) orig_amount
   FROM table;
```

Is it possible somehow to translate it into SAS? It is not working in `proc sql` step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use nor know SAS, however if it is something what does not support window functions, you can replace it by joins. I assume you want second argument of coalesce as the balance of oldest record of those in acc_id group, hence:

```
select acc_id,
  time,
  approved_amount,
  balance,
  coalesce(approved_amount, acc_id_to_balance.balance_fallback)
from table t
join (
  select t.acc_id, t.balance as balance_fallback
  from (
    select acc_id, min(time) as min_time
    from table
    group by acc_id
  ) acc_id_to_min_time
  join table t on acc_id_to_min_time.acc_id = t.acc_id and acc_id_to_min_time.min_time = t.time
) acc_id_to_balance on t.acc_id = acc_id_to_balance.acc_id
```

Just worked out in head, didn't try. Problems might appear in case of duplicate minimal time, which would require another level of grouping.

Comment: Thanks, seems to be working after I added `t.` subscript before the column names!

Answer (score 0):

This is how you would do that in SAS since unlike SQL when you use a data step it will process the data in the order that it appears in the source dataset.

```
data want;
  set table ;
  by acc_id time;
  if first.id then first_balance=balance;
  retain first_balance;
  orig_amount = coalesce(approved_amount,first_balance);
run;
```